# Stereo 70 where is it?

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, romania

I have ortho photos of Romania in Stereo 70 and GPS data in WGS84 of the same country : I want to associate the two series of data.

At the moment, I can't find Stereo 70 in the list of CRS : does it exist ?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? If you can't find the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) your photo is using, you can usually create a custom one in your software.

Answer (score 3):

spatialreference.org knows the projection, but gives no proj string for it.

QGIS 1.8.0 doesn't know it either, but QGIS 2.0 and GDAL 1.10.0 have the definition:

`+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.84 +units=m +no_defs`

You can add it to QGIS 1.8.0 as Custom CRS and work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

And it can be [easily found](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3844/) online. Unless you meant if it exists in some specific software, then you might want to add what you're using.